Deleted Older Version still showing Version Number as Latest One
I need to delete all version of item and keep only the latest one.
I tried using Powershell to delete Remove-ItemVersion $version; but after deletion version number still showing as latest one instead of 1.
How to delete older version and keep latest version as version 1.

To delete older versions of an item in Sitecore using PowerShell and ensure that only the latest version remains as version 1, you can use the Sitecore PowerShell Extensions module. Here I'm adding script to delete all versions except for the latest one:
$itemPath = "sitecore/content/YourItemPath" # Change this to your item path
$item = Get-Item -Path $itemPath

if ($item.Versions.Count -gt 1) {
    $latestVersion = $item.Versions.GetLatestVersion()
    $latestVersionNumber = $latestVersion.Version.Number

    # Iterate through all versions and delete the ones that are not the latest
    foreach ($version in $item.Versions.GetVersions()) {
        if ($version.Version.Number -ne $latestVersionNumber) {
            Remove-ItemVersion -Item $item -Version $version.Version.Number -Confirm:$false
        }
    }

    # Set the latest version as version 1
    if ($latestVersion.Version.Number -ne 1) {
        # Create a new version 1 and copy the latest version content to it
        $newVersion = $item.Versions.AddVersion(1)
        $newVersion.Editing.BeginEdit()

        # Copy the fields from the latest version to the new version 1
        foreach ($field in $latestVersion.Fields) {
            $newVersion.Fields[$field.Name].Value = $field.Value
        }

        $newVersion.Editing.EndEdit()

        # Optionally, remove the old latest version after setting it as version 1
        Remove-ItemVersion -Item $item -Version $latestVersion.Version.Number -Confirm:$false
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "There is only one version, nothing to delete."
}

Hope this help!!

$item.Versions.Rebuild() not working. getting doesn't contain definition for rebuild.

@aditya I have updated my answer try this script. It should work for you.

still not working parameter Database cannot be found

@aditya I have updated my answer again try this script. Let me know in  case you face any issues.

Try to resave it using the code below. It is an example for just 1 item, you can make the loop for all the children.
# Define the item path
$itemPath = "sitecore/content/Your/Item/Path"

# Get the item
$item = Get-Item -Path $itemPath

# Check if the item exists
if ($item -ne $null) {
    # Get all versions of the item
    $versions = Get-ChildItem -Path $item -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Version -ne $item.Versions.Latest.Version }

    # Loop through the versions and remove them
    foreach ($version in $versions) {
        Remove-ItemVersion -Item $version -Force
    }

    # Re-save the latest version
    $latestVersion = Get-Item -Path $itemPath -Version $item.Versions.Latest.Version
    $latestVersion.Editing.BeginEdit()
    $latestVersion.Editing.EndEdit()
    
    Write-Host "Old versions deleted. Latest version is now version 1."
} else {
    Write-Host "Item not found."
}


no this is not working.

As per my knowledge and research about it, you can't directly change a Sitecore item's version. So when you see all other versions it creates a new version like below.

In the Content or Experience Editor, go to the item's "Versions" tab and click "Add." This creates a new version with a unique ID. You can then edit this new version as needed. Remember, Sitecore automatically manages version IDs, it's focus is to create new versions to track changes and maintain your content's history.
But if you want to give version a unique name then you can provide it under the version tab in the Version Name field.

Hope this helps.

You can use below powershell snippet to remove all the item versions and keep only one version on the item, with the version number as 1.
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{{ItemID}}" -Language "en" -Version 1

$fields = $item | Get-ItemField
$latestVersionItem = $item.Versions.GetLatestVersion()
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
$fields | ForEach-Object{
   $item.Fields[$_].Value = $latestVersionItem.Fields[$_].Value
}
$item.Editing.EndEdit()

# Read all item version except first one and remove them
$itemVersions = $item.Versions.GetVersions() | Where-Object { $_.Version -ne 1 }
foreach ($itemVersion in $itemVersions) {
    $itemVersion |  Remove-ItemVersion
}

In the above snippet, all the fields(retrieved through Get-ItemField function) content on the latest version of the item is copied to the version number 1 and then all the other version are removed except the first version.
This will make sure you have the latest content on the first version of the item as well as have only version of the respective item.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.
